# SQL Append Other Column if 1 Column Contains the same Data

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, radgrid

My query displays the following:

```
╔════════╦═════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ itemNo ║ buyerNo ║ sellerNo ║ itemDesc ║
╠════════╬═════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ 1      ║ B1      ║ S1       ║ Item1    ║
╠════════╬═════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ 2      ║ B2      ║ S2       ║ Item2    ║ 
╠════════╬═════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ 2      ║ B3      ║ S3       ║ Item2    ║ 
╠════════╬═════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ 3      ║ B4      ║ S4       ║ Item3    ║ 
╠════════╬═════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ 3      ║ B5      ║ S5       ║ Item3    ║ 
╚════════╩═════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

In the table above, `itemNo` `2` and `3` are duplicated.

I would like to group `buyerNo` and `sellerNo` into the same cell if `itemNo` is found to be duplicated. `itemDesc` is identical for each `itemNo`.

```
╔════════╦═════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ itemNo ║ buyerNo ║ sellerNo ║ itemDesc ║
╠════════╬═════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ 1      ║ B1      ║ S1       ║ Item1    ║
╠════════╬═════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ 2      ║ B2, B3  ║ S2, S3   ║ Item2    ║ <-itemNo 2 combined
╠════════╬═════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ 3      ║ B4, B5  ║ S4, S5   ║ Item3    ║ <-itemNo 3 combined
╚════════╩═════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

Below is my current query:

```
public IQueryable GetAllInventorySummary()
    {
        var query = from summary in dataContext.Q_TBL_INVENTORY_SUMMARIES

                    group summary by new
                    {
                        itemNo = summary.itemNo,
                        buyerNo= summary.buyerNo,
                        sellerNo= summary.sellerNo,
                        itemDesc = summary.itemDesc,

                    } into grp
                    select new
                    {
                        itemNo = grp.Key.itemNo ,
                        buyerNo= grp.Key.buyerNo,
                        sellerNo= grp.Key.sellerNo,
                        itemDesc = grp.Key.itemDesc,
                    };
        return query;
    }
```

Which then gets parsed into my main method:

```
RadGrid1.DataSource = inventory.GetAllInventorySummary();
```

Comment: First, if you want to group by `itemNo` and `itemDesc`, then why do you group by `new { itemNo, buyerNo, sellerNo, itemDesc }` and not `new { itemNo, itemDesc }`?

Comment: @Rafalon it is a new requirement to append the columns `itemNo` and `sellerNo` now. I'm new to `LinqToSql` to I am quite lost.

Comment: if I comment off `itemNo` and `itemDesc` in `group summary by new`, how do I select the 2 values in the `select new` part?

Comment: It's `buyerNo` and `sellerNo` that you should comment, see D-Shih's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `GROUPBY and GROUP_CONCAT` function to achieve your expected output.

```
SELECT itemNo,
       group_concat(buyerNo),
       group_concat(sellerNo),
       itemDesc
FROM summary
GROUP BY itemNo
```

Comment: Code in OP's question looks more like LinqToSql than SQL

Comment: @Sadikhasan I would not need to `group summary by new` `into grp`, just this statement will suffice?

Comment: @Rafalon I dont know `LinqToSql` but I try to give answer as per my knowledge.

Comment: @Sadikhasan please delete this then. This isn't related to writing SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to only group by `itemNo` and `itemDesc`, then use `string.Join` connect string values.

You can try to use linq to SQL `select` data from DB first, then do linq `group by`.

```
var summaryList = (from summary in dataContext.Q_TBL_INVENTORY_SUMMARIES
                       select summary).ToList(); 


var result = from i in summaryList
              group i by new
                {
                    itemNo = i.itemNo,
                    itemDesc = i.itemDesc

                } into grp
                select new
                {
                    itemNo = grp.Key.itemNo,
                    buyerNo = string.Join(",", grp.Select(i => i.buyerNo)),
                    sellerNo = string.Join(",", grp.Select(i => i.sellerNo)),
                    itemDesc = grp.Key.itemDesc
                };
```

[c# demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KlebFb)

**Result**

```
1 B1 S1 Item1
2 B2,B3 S2,S3 Item2
3 B4,B5 S4,S5 Item3
```

---

**EDIT**

Because of *Linq-to-SQL* can't  translate to SQL (thank for @Panagiotis Kanavos point out)

I would suggest you execute SQL statement by `EF` `SqlQuery` method, that can make your expected result from `DB`. then binding by `ORM`.

The performance might better than my first solution.

Create a `SummaryDTO` to carry your result data.

```
public class SummaryDTO {
    public int itemNo { get; set; }
    public string buyerNo { get; set; }
    public string sellerNo { get; set; }
    public string itemDesc { get; set; }
}


var result = dataContext.Q_TBL_INVENTORY_SUMMARIES
        .SqlQuery("SELECT itemNo,
                           group_concat(buyerNo) buyerNo,
                           group_concat(sellerNo) sellerNo,
                           itemDesc
                  FROM summary
                  GROUP BY itemNo").ToList<SummaryDTO>();
```

Comment: can `string.join` work if my `buyerNo` and `sellerNo` may be in `VarChar`? I met the error `The specified type 'String' is not a valid provider type.` I need some time to verify as I do not have access to my DB yet.

Comment: `String.Join` in a *Linq-to-SQL* or *EF* query? How is this going to translate to SQL?

Comment: after testing, i met the error of `The specified type 'String' is not a valid provider type.`. continued thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52532181/the-specified-type-string-is-not-a-valid-provider-type?noredirect=1#comment92004189_52532181

Comment: @D-Shish you didn't change your code at all. That `summaryList ` is still an IQueryable. In fact, loading everything in memory would be a *very* bad idea and one of the most common bugs and performance killers when it comes to ORMs in general

Comment: @D-Shish That `ToList()` is the serious bug I was talking about. Imagine loading 1M rows in memory